# How to retrieve button position?

Tags: java, android, button

I've created a Relative layout that will change a button position when I touch it. Using OnTouchListener. But I want when I release the button (ACTION_UP), it go to it's own position before this operation. Can anyone help me out please?

My code : (inside on Create)

...

```
this.relative_layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();
                    my_button.setX(x);
                    my_button.setY(y);
                } else if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP)
                /* here's the issue that I'm
                 * asking for help about
                 * What to do to return the button position back
                 * Like it was? */
                    return true;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, setX does:

> Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is
>   equivalent to setting the translationX property to be the difference
>   between the x value passed in and the current left property.

So to reverse that, use `setTranslationX(0);`

Same thing for the Y-  `setTranslationY(0);`